# id3 information

Tags: mp3, id3

I want to know about the id3 metadata, I am eager in extracting the album art from the mp3 file.

Can u help me in suggesting a page which says about the id3 tag information (especially the images). I cant able to access the id3 developer info website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/

id3lib provides a nice API for reading id3 info from MP3s, it's used quite widely as well.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to know the internal structure of the ID3 Tags are to take some time in hand and read the specifications. I have a write up in this topic, you might want to read that too.

[What Are ID3 Tags All About](http://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/what-are-id3-tags-all-about)

[Synchronization Safe Integers](http://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/synch-safe/)

And ofcourse the Developer Information: http://www.id3.org/Developer_Information

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this page? http://www.id3.org/Developer_Information
If you can't access that page you're almost dead in the water.